# How to assign variable to external array file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, github-pages

In a js script (part of a Githubpages project), I currently have a variable defined as an array:

```
var myArray= [
 'one string',
 'two string',
 'red string',
 'blue string',
];
```

The thing is, my real array declared as the variable's value is very long, with plenty of long strings. I want to put the array in a separate file and  still declare the variable as that array. Is there some way to do this by referencing the location of the file,

Like,

In folder "arrays", filename "dr.suess":

```
  [
  'one string',
  'two string',
  'red string',
  'blue string',
   ];
```

In my JavaScript:

```
var myArray = https://user.github.io/arrays/dr.suess
```

Or is this just not gonna work? Preferably an answer **not** with jQuery, cause I don't understand it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following `.html` file

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
      const arr = [1,2,3]
    </script>

    <script>
      console.log(arr)
    </script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Inside the `<head>` tag I have two `<script>` tags. Despite being separate tags, they both run on the same page and in the order they appear on the page, meaning first, `const arr = [1,2,3]` will evaluate and create variable named `arr`, then `console.log(arr)` will log this variable

You can move first script in one file and second script in another file, then include these files in `<script>` tags, like this

```
<script src="arrays/myArrayFile.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Pay attention to the path of included files

Comment: I think the first script you say to tag is pathed to a file that just has my array in it. The second script you say to tag, I think, is my main.js file with the var myArray declaration. So I understand that you can tag both the scripts in the head element. However, how do I make it clear either on my main.js or the HTML itself that var myArray on script main.js is defined as script myArrayFile?

Comment: Never mind, I understand your answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are almost right, but take a closer look to my script tags (or files). In the first one I don't just create an array, I create it and assign it to a variable `arr`. Javascript in my second tag can see this variable and, obviously, can access the created array. This, I think, is the simplest thing you can do in your case with pure html and css. As things get more advanced, you start using webpack/modules/requires to allow you to include external files in your javascript code, but this would be out of scope of this question

Comment: Yes, I understand now that rather than separating the variable and its array, you kept the variable and array together on a separate script, and the rest of my main.js can access that variable. This helps a lot to clean up my code.